# MacBook Pro early 2015 not turning on and not charging

Tags: macbook-pro, battery

I'm far away from civilization thats why I need your help guys. My problem is: MacBook Pro 13" early 2015 is not turning on and charging and the trackpad is also dead.

1. Charger's LED does not shine by any light(red/orange/green) . But I tested my charger with another MacBook and charger is working.
2. I tried to connect another charger. First 1-2 minute I can see green light and then LED turns off.
3. Trackpad is not react to any action (like double click). Right now this is just some plastic area
4. Turn off and turn on battery connector also didn't help me.

The laptop did not receive any damage and was not flooded with water. Day or two before I got it from safe and checked my email then closed it and put to the safe again(hotel standard safe) (everything was okay but I didn't remember battery charge percent at that day) then I open and figured out that MacBook is dead.

Comment: what happens when you disconnect the battery and then insert the charger, will it start?

Comment: No:( and diode on charger also didn't work but I tested charger and everything was working with another MacBook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your MacBook is dead.

Without putting hands on, I would guess that you have an issue with the DC-in board.  It's the interface between your charger and the logic board and battery.

[image]

You have already done the requisite diagnostics:

- Verified the your charger works
- Verified that known working charger doesn't work on your MBP
- Attempted to boot with battery disconnected

One final test you could attempt (if you have it available to you) is to use a battery from a known good MacBook Pro of the same model.  If it boots, you will verify that the logic board is functional and confirm it's the DC-in board.

As far as the trackpad goes, it has no relevance here.  It's ultimately a USB device and if the MBP has no power, the trackpad won't either.

If it is the [DC in board](http://radnex.us/mbp-dc-in-2013-2015-15inch), it's a relatively easy and inexpensive fix.  [iFixit.com](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Pro+13-Inch+Retina+Display+Early+2015+MagSafe+DC-In+Board+Replacement/38516) has excellent instructions.  It is still possible that it could be a logic board failure, but based on my experience that's it's unlikely.

Comment: Thank you for nice advice. But can I verify is it dc-in board without another battery? I just have magsafe MacBook and some screwdrivers :) not a lot I know..I just want verify that laptop is working just problem with some small board..

Comment: With a shortage of tools, I would probably bite the bullet and spend the $20 USD and get a DC-in board.  If it fixes the problem, you're good.  If not, it's the logic board which means a very expensive fix.  One of the reasons I believe it's this board is that your battery isn't charging either.  That's too many power rails to fail simultaneously (not that's it's impossible, just unlikely)

Comment: Okay thank you very much. By the way, can u explain how battery from another MacBook can help me if problem in dc-in board not in battery? Or do I miss something?

Comment: You have a dead battery that won't power the logic board.  If you put a good battery in and it works, you've confirmed it's the DC in board.  If it doesn't work, then it's the logic board

Comment: maybe you know why it can happened?

Comment: Any number of things from a power surge to a defective component.