# Why does the MagSafe Connector Charging Indicator flicker?

Tags: macbook-pro, charging, power, thunderbolt-display, magsafe

The MagSafe Connector charging indicator light flickers when connected to my MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015). The MagSafe cable comes from a Thunderbolt Display (2015) and has a [L-style MagSafe connector](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT203207). It uses a [MagSafe to MagSafe 2 Converter](https://www.apple.com/uk/shop/product/MD504ZM/A/magsafe-to-magsafe-2-converter) to connect to the MacBook. The MacBook does not charge when connected.

[image: flickering magsafe light when connected]

The flickering continues after disconnecting the cable.

[image: flickering magsafe light after disconnecting]

The issue may be with the cable itself, because using the laptop’s MagSafe Power Adapter connected to an outlet works fine.

Does anybody have any suggestions on why this is happening and what a possible fix could be? Thank you!

Comment: Is that a genuine Apple Magsafe adapter?  That looks like an L adapter going into a MS2 adapter.

Comment: Doesn't seem genuine to me. Can you [identify it](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT203207)?

Comment: Also, do you have a constant power supply? (The light can flicker because the power supply isn't constant) Is it behaving the same when you Mac is opened?

Comment: That is ***not*** a dupe.  The linked question is about an adapter that’s connected to a Mac.  This question it is very clear that the charger isn’t connected and the light is still flashing.

Answer (score 2):

#### You have a failed connector

It could either be the MagSafe “L” connector attached to the cable/power brick or it could be the MagSafe to MagSafe2 (MG to MG2) adapter.

The tell tale sign is that LED should *never* come on unless it’s connected to the DC-in board of the MacBook and successfully communicates.  MagSafe chargers use the 1-Wire signaling to communicate between the DC-in board on the Mac and [the chip inside the MagSafe connector](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ds2413.pdf).

This is what turns the light amber when charging, green when fully charged, or flashes when there’s a problem.  The fact it’s happening when the connecter is disconnected means the problem is with solely with the connector end and not the Mac.

There is an excellent write up entitled [Teardown and exploration of Apple's Magsafe connector](http://www.righto.com/2013/06/teardown-and-exploration-of-magsafe.html) that goes into further detail on this topic.  It’s worth the read.

#### Possible Fixes & Diagnosis

- Remove the MG-MG2 adapter.  If the LED stops flickering, it’s likely the adapter has failed.  It’s easy and inexpensive to to test by getting a replacement
- Clean the contacts on the “L” connector and both sides of the MG-MG2 adapter.  Use 90% isopropyl alcohol (IPA) and not the normal 70% you get at the pharmacy/chemist. You can use a stiff nylon brush (like a toothbrush), but just don’t use water.  Allow the IPA to evaporate completely before using.
- If the LED continues to flicker *after* removing the MG-MG2 adapter, you might need to get a new charger.

**Remember to unplug from mains before doing any of these services!**

#### Further Reading:

- [How to fix/clean burnt MagSafe 2 connection](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/387347/119271)
- [What are specs of this MagSafe wire, and what is its purpose?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/302625/119271)
- [Macbook mid-2010: no power after ssd upgrade](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/347943/119271)